# memory corrupted using std::vector in constructor

Tags: c++, memory

Given an array of strings, I am writing a class to separated them into different groups according to their length, i.e. the ones of same length goes to the same group. The number of groups and the size of each group are unknown.

**My idea is following:**
I use a private data member `std::vector<std::vector<std::int> > m_groups`, with the intention that the outer vector maintains the groups, and the inner vector tracks all the indices of strings belong to one group.

The problem is, once I push strings into the vector, some of my data members are corrupted. Could anyone please have a look?

Here is the simplified code:

```
class A {

public:
    A(std::string words[], int num, int c1[], int m, int c2[], int n);
    ~A();

    void print_state();

private:

    int *m_var; 
    int m_Nvar;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::int> > m_doms;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::int> > m_groups;
    std::vector<std::string> > m_words;

    int *m_cst1;
    int *m_cst2;
    int m_Ncst;
};
```

in the constructor:
    A::print_cst2()
    {
       for (int c = 0; c < m_Ncst; c++)
       {
           printf("%d ", m_cst2[4*c]);
           printf("%d ", m_cst2[4*c+1]);
           printf("%d ", m_cst2[4*c+2]);
           printf("%d ", m_cst2[4*c+3]);
       }
    }

```
A::A(std::string words[], int num,
    int c1[], int m, int c2[], int n) {

    ...
    m_cst1 = new int[m/2];
    m_cst2 = new int[n/4];
    m_Ncst = n/4;
    m_Nvar = m/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=4)
    {
        m_cst2[i] = c2[i];
        m_cst2[i+1] = c2[i+1];
        m_cst2[i+2] = c2[i+2];
        m_cst2[i+3] = c2[i+3];
    }

    print_cst2();  // (1) we print the m_cst2 
    // we are only interested, the words of length smaller than m_max_len
    // put m_max_len number of empty vectors (groups) in the group vector
    for (int i = 0; i < m_max_len; i++)
    {   
        m_groups.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    }   
    print_cst2();  // (2) we print the m_cst2 again 

    // go through every words and copy words of interest to m_words
    // push the index of the word to the group it belongs to (by its length)
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < num; i++, k++)
    {   
        int len = words[i].length();
        if (len > m_max_len)
            continue;
        m_words.push_back(words[i]);
        m_groups[len].push_back(k);
    }

    // you can ignore this part: link the group to another structure
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Nvar; i++)
    {
         m_doms.push_back(m_groups[m_cst1[i]]);
    }

    ...
}

...
```

I compiled the code and run. The data in the end of array `m_cst2` gets corrupted. This seems connected to the use of `std::vector`. [User comingstorm provided an interesting clue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197448/two-dimensional-vector-in-c-inefficient-with-dynamic-sized-sub-vectors): *the outer `std::vector` stores an array of fixed-size `std::vector<int>` datastructures in its heap allocation.* Is that the answer? Not sure though. So, post this and ask for suggestions.

PS: if you have a better idea to do this task, please do tell me ... if you need more information, please post.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Why didn't you use vector here?  `m_cst1 = new int[m/2];
    m_cst2 = new int[n/4];`  There is no need for code like this if you have `vector`.  A `vector` was created so that dynamic arrays using raw `new[]\delete[]` are not necessary.

Comment: Also, how are you calling this function.  Depending on the arguments, the first loop will corrupt memory.

Comment: Yes, I can use vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you posted is the actual code you're using, then this will corrupt memory.

Assume `n` is 4.

```
m_cst2 = new int[n/4];  // so you have room for 1 item
m_Ncst = n/4;
m_Nvar = m/2;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=4)
{
    m_cst2[i] = c2[i];      // valid
    m_cst2[i+1] = c2[i+1];  // memory overwrite
    m_cst2[i+2] = c2[i+2];  // memory overwrite
    m_cst2[i+3] = c2[i+3];  // memory overwrite
}
```

There is no need to go further.  The value of `n` is 4, and clearly you are going to go out-of-bounds in `m_cst2` when you write to `m_cst2[1], m_cst2[2]`, etc. as the only valid entry is `m_cst2[0]`.

So your memory corruption probably has nothing to do with `std::vector` (it is very difficult to mess up a vector of objects), and it more than likely has to do with the code above.

Also, you should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]/delete[]` in your code.  If you're going to use `vector` for one thing, why not take advantage of it wherever and whenever you can?

Comment: that is the problem. it should be m_cst2 = new int[n] ... :( Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements below. In particular you had an off by 1 index error and the incrementation of `k` was incorrect:

```
CwordSolver::CwordSolver(std::string words[], int num,
int c1[], int m, int c2[], int n) {

    ...

    // we are only interested, the words of length smaller than m_max_len
    m_groups.resize(0);
    m_groups.resize(m_max_len, std::vector<int>());

    // go through every words and copy words of interest to m_words
    // push the index of the word to the group it belongs to (by its length)
    int k = 0;    // the index in m_words
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {   
        int len = words[i].length();
        if (len >= m_max_len)
            continue;
        m_words.push_back(words[i]);
        m_groups[len].push_back(k);
        k++;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You are right! the fix of increment of k is definitely a good one! One question: why resize to 0 and then resize to the size we need?

Comment: If it is the first time it is used then the `resize(0)` is not needed. If not then it will overwrite the data that was in the vector.

Comment: I see... so, the resize to m_max_len is basically same as pushing empty vectors to the m_groups. and it does not help fix the corruption (tested.)

Comment: If resize(0) is just meant to remove what's already in the vector, why not use vector.clear()?

Comment: I guess `clear()` would be equivalent. I cant see `m_cst2` being used anywhere so I cant help with that.

Comment: sorry, I just added the code related to m_cst2. I print mcst2 after I initialize it before the push the vector and after. will that help?